# store internally a PDF from internet and display into WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I'm developing an app for iOS 8.1 using Xcode 6.1.1

And I want to download a PDF from internet, store in to my iPad and then load it into a webview; this is the PDF test:

[image: pdf screenshot]

this is the result I get on iPad after trying to display it on my WebView:

[image: iPad screenshot]

this is my code so far...

```
// Get the PDF Data from the url in a NSData Object
    NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ferc.gov/docs-filing/elibrary/larg-file.pdf"]];

    // Store the Data locally as PDF File
    NSArray *searchPaths            = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolderPath    = searchPaths[0];
    NSString *archivePath           = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"larg-file.pdf"];

    [pdfData writeToFile:archivePath atomically:YES];

    // Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:archivePath];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_webView setDelegate:self];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

How do I make this work?

**EDIT: this is the answer**

```
NSArray *searchPaths            = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolderPath    = searchPaths[0];
    NSString *archivePath           = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"larg-file.pdf"];

    if (![Functions isAlreadyStoredinDeviceFileWithName:@"larg-file.pdf"]) {

        NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ferc.gov/docs-filing/elibrary/larg-file.pdf"]];
        [pdfData writeToFile:archivePath atomically:YES];
    }


    // Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
    NSURL *url                  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:archivePath];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_webView setDelegate:self];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: How you loaded that in Webview ?

Comment: Why use a web view? Why not use a `QLPreviewController`?

Comment: FYI - your logic to construct the `Documents` path is wrong and won't work under iOS 8.

Comment: @rmaddy: what about now with the update I changed the way I get the documents path

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the tip!, I'll see how to implement QLPreviewController, but first I need to know how to save it correctly for presenting it properly either on WebView or QLPreviewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
```

Attempts to formulate a directory within the application bundle. You do not have write access to the application bundle. Your file therefore isn't saved.

Check out [`-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:) or [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) for how to get the path to the user's documents folder.